# SQL Query inline IF ELSE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parameter @year to select which table to select from, like for example:

```
SELECT * FROM account2014
or
SELECT * FROM account2016
```

Can I IF ELSE inside an SQL Query? like:

```
SELECT * FROM (IF @year = '2014' THEN account2014 ELSE IF @year = '2016' THEN account2016)
```

I also tested

```
SELECT * FROM account@year
```

But it's not working I think it's outputting account'2014', how can I fix this? I'm open to any suggestion for other ways, please help

Comment: Use dynamic sql.

Comment: Bad database design, think about from now after 20-30 year, how you will manage that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
if @year = '2014'
begin
    SELECT * FROM account2014 where @year = '2014'
end
else if @year = '2016'
begin  
    SELECT * FROM account2016 where @year = '2016'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT *
FROM account2014
WHERE @year = 2014
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM account2016
WHERE @year = 2016;
```

As a note:  You should be storing all the account data in a single table with a column for `year`.  Breaking up the same data into multiple tables is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: I have millions of records, that's why I break the records into different year to have faster searching speed

Comment: @Hanzou . . . That is a really bad reason.  Databases are designed to handle tables with millions of rows -- and even more.

Comment: "Union all" used for  both table have  equal number of col's

Answer (score 1):

USE dynamic query

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM account'+@Year)
```

Comment: What if I have a Where clause? Will it look like this? EXEC('SELECT * FROM account'+@Year+' WHERE name like '%John%')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dynamic SQL`

```
Declare @sql varchar(max), @year int
set @year = 2014 --assign year that you want.
set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM account'+ convert(varchar,@year) 
exec(@sql)
```